# failed to set property into delayer

Tags: apache-camel

I faced a problem, when I use this spring-camel context I got error about type conversion from String to Long, related to second {{retryCount}}. When I start debugging I realised that BaseTypeConverterRegistry#convertTo method got retryCount value (let say 10) in the first occurence and value "{{retryCount}}" in the second case (delayer component), so I don't know why.

My Spring Camel context:

```
<propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:camel.properties" id="properties" />
  <route id="mojorun">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?delay=0&amp;repeatCount=1" />
    <loop>
      <spring:constant>{{retryCount}}</spring:constant>
      <spring:inOnly uri="bean:mojo?method=shout"/>
      <spring:delay>
        <spring:constant>{{retryCount}}</spring:constant>
      </spring:delay>
    </loop>
  </route>
```

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: <camel.version>2.10.0</camel.version>

Comment: and also I found that if I use it that way  `<method ref="myDelayBean" method="getDelayMe" />` with bean which returns delay (in turn it sets its field from property file) it works.

Comment: So, Delayer component can't parse value from property, it throws `TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.Long with value {{retryCount}}` so it parses {{retryCount}} to value for loop and doesn't for delayer

Comment: Same question posted on Camel with an answer - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/failed-to-set-property-into-Delayer-td5746991.html

Comment: Hello Claus, yes it was me on the Camel forum. Thank you for your answer, we can continue discussion on Camel